# Defer notification deep linking until after react-native expo app is fully loaded

Tags: react-native, notifications, navigation, expo, event-listener

I would like to defer the deep-link navigation event tied to a notification until the app is fully loaded after my react-native app is opened on notification click.

Currently, my notification listener is in my `App.tsx` file. The deep linking works as expected when the app is backgrounded, but when the notification triggers the app to open, the navigation event is kicked off before the App has a chance to fully load. This means that although I do get deep linked to the correct location, some of my assets aren't yet loaded and my auth logic is all bypassed.

Is there a way to have a notification open the app, but wait until everything is loaded (specifically the AppLoading component has finished running its functions) to navigate to the deep linking location? I can think of some hack-y seeming ways to do this but is there an established pattern that is commonly used?

Comment: I was downvoted so i cleaned up my question a bit to make it more targeted, but it would've been nice if the person who downvoted me would've left a brief comment explaining why, especially since this is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle this but I found a way to get my notifications working.

(1) I created an action called `registerAppLoaded` and a state variable `appLoaded` that I dispatch once my `AppLoading` component finishes its `startAsync` functions.

(2) When a notification comes in, I first check to see if `appLoaded` is true. If so, I navigate to the destination sent along with the notification. If not, I put the notification in the store and carry on with firing up the app.

(3) in the `AppLoading` `onFinish` function, I check to see if there is a notification. If so, and it is marked `new`, I grab it and use the params to navigate. Then I dispatch an action that sets `navigation.new = false`

Seems to work exactly the way i need it to!

Here is my code if anyone else is dealing with this issue:

App.tsx:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    Notifications.addListener((notification) => {
      if (notification.origin === "received") { 
        return; 
      } else {
        const appLoaded = store.getState().general.appLoaded
        if (appLoaded) {
          NavigationService.navigate(notification.data.navigate, {id:notification.data.id , shouldRefresh: true})
        } else {
          // save notification as new
          store.dispatch(addNotification(notification, true));
        }
      };
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {Platform.OS === "ios" && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
            <ErrorBoundary backup={<AppError />}>
              <AppNavigator />
            </ErrorBoundary>
          </View>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

AppLoading.tsx:

```
class AppLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  _loadResourcesAsync = async() => {
    await this.props.fetchUserOnboarding(this.props.userId);
    if (this.props.userDevice && this.props.userDevice.id) {
      this.props.registerUserDevice(this.props.userId, this.props.userDevice.id)
    }
    // register that the app has finished loading in the store; this will be used to determine if a notification's deep 
    // link should be immediatedly navigated to or if the navigation even shuold be deferred until after the app 
    // finishes loading
    await this.props.registerAppLoaded()
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = async () => {
    // if a notification triggers the event listener but the app is not yet fully loaded, the deep link will be 
    // navigated to here instead of directly from the listener
    const notification = this.props.userNotifications && this.props.userNotifications[0]
    if (notification && notification.new && notification.origin != 'recieved') {
      this.props.addNotification(notification, false) // set notification.new = false
      this.props.navigation.navigate(notification.data.navigate, {id: notification.data.id, shouldRefresh: true})
    } else if (this.props.showGoalsPrompt) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Goal");
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeFeed");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
        onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

actions.tsx:

```
export const registerAppLoaded = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.REGISTER_APP_LOADED,
      payload: true
    });
  };
}

export const addNotification = (notification, isNew=false) => {
  return dispatch => {
    notification.new = isNew // indicate whether this is a new notification or if it has been seen
    dispatch({
      type:types.ADD_USER_NOTIFICATION,
      payload: notification,
    })
  };
}
```